# Playing aroud with Haskell State

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, state

So I am trying to implement a Haskell game using the State and as a part of the game, I wanted to implement ways to save a current player's name and retrieve it when called. I have helper functions popStack and pushStack which pops and pushes values into stack respectively.

The current code:

```
 import Control.Monad.State

 data Gamestate = Gamestate {
     gamestack :: [String],
     gamememory :: String
 }

 type NewGameState = State GameState

 popStack :: NewGameState String
 popStack = state $ \st -> case gamestack st of
     [] -> (0.0,st)
     x:xs -> (x,st { gamestack = xs })

 pushStack :: String -> NewGameState ()
 push d = modify  $ \st -> st { gamestack = d : gamestack st }
```

I have come up with the following code for saveName and getName.

```
saveName :: NewGameState ()
saveName = do
        memory <-head   
        pushStack $ x

getName :: NewGameState ()
getName = do
        memory <- head gamestack
        popStack $ memory
```

The code snippets above return type errors. I don't understand State Monads much. So how do I copy the current players name at the top of the gamestack into gamememory using saveName and push the gamememory at the top of gamestack when I use getName?

Sorry if its a bit confusing. I am an ESL speaker. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should include the error messages you get, however I notice that you have an obvious error in `saveName` with `memory <- head`.  You're in the state monad, not the function monad.

Comment: Why do you think you need a stack? A key/value store (perhaps a Map) would probably be much more useful.  Stacks allow you to push multiple objects; if you do that, how will you retrieve the player's name from under the other things in the stack?  How will you know which items are which?  If you only put the name there, and nothing else, why bother with a stack at all?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer your question by showing you the idiomatic way to do what you are trying to do.  As I go along I'm going to point out what I fixed in your code.

First problem: You have inconsistent capitalization of `Gamestate`.  Capitalization matters in Haskell, so I renamed everything to `GameState`.

So after making that fixes, the first thing I did was define lenses to your two data type's fields.  This makes it much easier do stateful things that modify a subset of your state.  You will see this when I get to the implementations of the remaining functions:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Lens

data GameState = GameState
    { _gamestack  :: [String]
    , _gamememory ::  String
    }

gamestack :: Lens' GameState [String]
gamestack k (GameState s m) = fmap (\s' -> GameState s' m) (k s)

gamememory :: Lens' GameState String
gamememory k (GameState s m) = fmap (\m' -> GameState s m') (k m)

type NewGameState = State GameState
```

Note that you don't have to manually define lenses like this.  Instead of defining `gamememory` and `gamestack`, you could also have done this instead:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}  -- Note the extension

import Control.Lens

data GameState = GameState
    { _gamestack  :: [String]
    , _gamememory ::  String
    }

makeLenses ''GameState
```

Whichever way you choose, once we have these lenses, we can write `push` and `pop` in such a way that they don't care what state they are acting on, as long as it is a list:

```
pop :: State [a] (Maybe a)
pop = do
    s <- get
    case s of
        []   -> return Nothing
        x:xs -> do
            put xs
            return (Just x)

push :: a -> State [a] ()
push d = modify (d:)
```

Notice that I changed `pop` to return a `Maybe` if the list is empty.  This is more idiomatic Haskell than defaulting to `0` or using `head`.

Using `push` and `pop`, it becomes very easy to transfer values between your game's memory and its stack:

```
saveName :: NewGameState ()
saveName = do
    memory <- use gamememory
    zoom gamestack (push memory)

getName :: NewGameState ()
getName = do
    m <- zoom gamestack pop
    case m of
        Nothing -> return ()
        Just x  -> gamememory .= x
```

Notice how I use `zoom` to localize `push` and `pop` to operate on either the `gamememory` or the `gamestack` fields.  `zoom` takes a lens to a sub-field and then runs the stateful action as if the entire state were just that sub-field.  This is cool because now `push` and `pop` are much more reusable and we don't have to bake in a specific choice of state data type into them.

This also uses `.=`, which sets a given field.  It's basically the same as:

```
lens .= x = zoom lens (put x)
```

To learn more about lenses, `(.=)`, and `zoom`, you might want to read [this post](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/05/program-imperatively-using-haskell.html) that I wrote.

Edit: By request, here is the lens-free version:

```
import Control.Monad.State

data GameState = GameState
    { gamestack  :: [String]
    , gamememory ::  String
    }

type NewGameState = State GameState

saveName :: NewGameState ()
saveName = do
    GameState stack memory <- get
    put (GameState (memory:stack) memory)

getName :: NewGameState ()
getName = do
    GameState stack memory <- get
    case stack of
        []   -> put (GameState stack memory)
        x:xs -> put (GameState xs    x     )
```

Comment: I'd hesitate to show lenses to a beginner. I love the library but we have cartoons about it's poor interface for beginners

Comment: @jozefg Normally I would agree, but `zoom` is the only elegant way to do updates of nested fields.

Comment: This is great! However I am merely a beginner and was wondering if there is a simpler, nonelegant way of writing the getName function without using lens and zoom?

Comment: @PaulK I added a lens-free version to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If something is on the right side of a `<-` than it has to be in that monad. So what you want here is something like

```
saveName :: NewGameState ()
saveName = do
  memory <- fmap gamememory get
  pushStack memory

getName = popStack
```

for `saveName` we `fmap` `gamememory` over the current state and store the result in `memory` than push that on the stack. We can actually write this as `get >>= pushStack . gamememory` if you want to be fancy.

`popStack` doesn't take any arguments so I'm not sure what you wanted there. My best guess is that it should just grab the last name we pushed on which just is a call to `popStack`.

Comment: To clarify, the getName action should push the gamememory at the top of gamestack.

Answer (score 1):

**`NewGameState`** is a poor name - it isn't a new game state at all, it's a monad that carries around a state.  I just called it `Game`.

**`pushStack` vs `push`** - You gave a signature named `pushStack` then a function named `push`.  Pick one.

**In `popStack` you have `[] -> (0.0, st)`**  Let's face it, `0.0` is not a string, so why are you trying to return it? Did you just not know what to do when popping an empty stack?  How about you use `""` instead?

**saveName and getName** Well you haven't even said what you want these to do.  It seems you accepted other answerer's interpretations so going with that, we can just use record update syntax.

In the end, here is some code that at least compiles:

```
import Control.Monad.State

data GameState = GameState {
    gamestack :: [String],
    gamememory :: String
}

type Game = State GameState

popStack :: Game (Maybe String)
popStack = state $ \st -> case gamestack st of
    [] -> (Nothing,st)
    x:xs -> (Just x,st { gamestack = xs })

pushStack :: String -> Game ()
pushStack d = modify  $ \st -> st { gamestack = d : gamestack st }

saveName :: Game ()
saveName = do
    memory <- gamememory `fmap` get
    pushStack memory

getName :: Game ()
getName = do
    newMem <- popStack
    case newMem of
       Nothing -> return ()
       Just n  -> modify (\x -> x { gamememory = n } )
```